# Passing parameters to @selector in performSelectorInBackground?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've read a about `@selector` but I couldn't find an answer to my question

I'm trying to pass parameters to `@selector`. this is a simple code about what I did :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NewsCell *cell = (NewsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSString *string = @"image.png";

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doSomeThing::) withObject:nil];
}

-(void) doSomeThing:(UITableViewCell *)newsCell imageName:(NSString *)imageName{
    NSLog(@"newsCell: %@", newsCell);
    NSLog(@"imageName: %@", imageName);
}
```

I've created new **UITableViewCell** called `cell`, it loads from another **nib** file called `NewsCell`

and created new **string** called `string`

The question is how to send `cell` and `string` as parameters to `@selector` in **performSelectorInBackground**, Any ideas ??

Thanks ..

Comment: You have the `doSomeThing:imageName` set up correctly but you need to change the way you call the function with `[doSomeThing:cell imageName:string]` inside a `dispatch_async` function.

Comment: By the way, I know you were probably trying to simply your example by doing this stuff in `viewDidLoad`, but you really shouldn't be creating/updating cells there. This `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` stuff should probably be performed in your `UITableViewDataSource` method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, not in `viewDidLoad`. See the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451).

Comment: @Rob that's right.. this code is just for example.. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass only one parameter using `performSelectorInBackground` (using the `withObject` parameter).

If you want to `doSomeThing` in the background with two parameters, you can:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self doSomeThing:cell imageName:string];
});
```

By the way, if `doSomeThing` is going to eventually do a UI update, make sure to dispatch that back to the main queue:

```
-(void) doSomeThing:(UITableViewCell *)newsCell imageName:(NSString *)imageName {

    // do your slow stuff in the background here

    NSLog(@"newsCell: %@", newsCell);
    NSLog(@"imageName: %@", imageName);

    // now update your UI

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // update your UI here
    });
}
```

---

And as a final caveat, if you're updating a cell asynchronously, if you want to be really careful, you may want to be sensitive to the fact that the cell may have scrolled off the screen by the time the asynchronous method completes (and worse, that the `UITableView` may have reused that cell for another row of the table). Thus, you might want to check to make sure the cell is still on screen. Thus, pass the `indexPath` parameter rather than the cell, and then use the `UITableView` method, [`cellForRowAtIndexPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW16), not to be confused with the very similarly named `UITableViewDataSource` method [`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW6), to see if it's still visible:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self doSomeThing:indexPath imageName:string];
});
```

And then

```
-(void) doSomeThing:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath imageName:(NSString *)imageName {

    // do your slow stuff in the background here

    NSLog(@"newsCell: %@", newsCell);
    NSLog(@"imageName: %@", imageName);

    // now update your UI

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UITableViewCell *newsCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (newsCell)
        {
            // the cell is still visible, so update your UI here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Super, I never thought of this ;)

Comment: definitely the best solution, great answer

Comment: `performSelectorInBackground` looks pale compared to this

Comment: it should be (dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) is that right ?? i think you have forgot ", 0"

Comment: @MujtabaAbbas Quite right. I revised my answer. I was just typing this in without the assistance of Xcode. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can pass an `NSDictionary*` or an `NSArray*` to `performSelectorInBackground`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    // Blah blah 
    NSDictionary* params = @{@"cell": cell, @"image": string};
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doSomething:) withObject:params];
}

-(void)doSomething:(NSDictionary*)params {
    UITableViewCell* cell = params[@"cell"];
    NSString* image = params[@"image"];

    // Blah blah...
}
```

I personally prefer `NSDictionary` to `NSArray` as it looks clearer.

Comment: This is fine if you don't mind changing `-doSomething:imageName:` such that it only takes one parameter, or providing another method that converts the dictionary into a call to `-doSomething:imageName:`. I don't think it's a "best" solution, though, because it avoids the problem that the OP asks about rather than solving it.

Comment: Hm that's a limitation of `performSelectorInBackground` I guess. It would be nice if they added a version like `performSelectorInBackground:withObject1:object2:` so on. But they didn't... Anyway `doSomething` is a method the OP **owns**, so there should be no trouble changing it.

Answer (score 2):

> The question is how to send 'cell' and 'string' as parameters to @selector in performSelectorInBackground, Any ideas ??

**You can't.** `@selector()` is a compiler directive which simply converts whatever is between the parentheses into an Objective-C selector -- you can't give it any other parameters. I think what you really want to do is to invoke the selector with parameters. The method you're trying to use only allows for a single parameter; there's no way to provide more than one.

**Use a block or invocation.** That doesn't mean that you don't have other options, though. You can use a block, as Rob describes, or you can create an instance of NSInvocation, add the necessary parameters, set the selector and target, and call `-invoke`.

Comment: Agreed. Lots of options here. If `doSomeThing` was doing a network request, I might also suggest he might also consider using a `NSOperationQueue` (where he can set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` so he doesn't submit too many concurrent requests if doing this on a really slow network) and which provides cancellation logic that GCD doesn't (so he don't risk getting this backlogged retrieving images for cells that may have long since scrolled out of view, yielding a really slow UX).

Answer (score 0):

You can only send one parameter with performSelectorInBackground.

You'll have to do some re-architecturing of your code.

To pass one of the parameters you do:

```
[self performSelectInBackground:@selector(doSomething:) withObject:cell];
```